# How can I exit a while loop based on input from a function in a function in C?

Tags: c

I have a while loop in my main function which calls a user defined function which calls another user defined function which calls `scanf` to read a pair of `double` values. I want my program to end when a non-numeric is entered.  I have my functions returning structures, and not 0/1. Is there a way to pass a false `scanf` return all the way through to break my while loop?

Can I declare a global variable and assign it to the `scanf` statement and then make an `if` statement about that variable in the `main` function?
Or will I have to change my functions to return int (0/1) and pass in my structures by reference?

This is probably a really bad explanation so here's my code for the parts involved in my question... The program is meant to read in a rectangle (by bottom left point and top right point) and a circle and say if their areas overlap. And I'm looking to put a break in the `while` loop in the `main` function...

```
typedef struct{double x,y;} point;
typedef struct{point a,b,c,d;} rectangle;
typedef struct{point o; double r;} circle;

point readPoint(){
    point p;
    scanf("%lf%lf", &p.x, &p.y);     //type "quit"
    return p;
}

rectangle readRectangle(){
    rectangle r;
    r.c=readPoint();
    r.b=readPoint();
    r.a.x=r.c.x;
    r.a.y=r.b.y;
    r.d.x=r.b.x;
    r.d.y=r.c.y;
    return r;
}

int main(void) {
    int a=0;
    rectangle r;
    circle c;

    while(1){
        printf("Enter rectangle:");
        r=readRectangle();            //break loop here if quit is entered
        printf("Enter circle:");
        c=readCircle();
        a=overlap(r, c);
        if (a==1)
            printf("The rectangle and the circle overlap.\n\n");
        else
            printf("The rectangle and the circle do not overlap.\n\n");
    }
    printf("Program completed normally.");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You have already listed some of the main options. Just go ahead and pick one of them. I personally would not recommend using a global but would go with the return value approach.

Comment: Using global variable is not good unless it is necessary.

Comment: another option add one more item in the structure.

Comment: bansai, can you elaborate on this a little bit? do you mean adding another item into the point structure? like a string to read quit? would that not affect the rest of the times i use that structure?

Comment: I'd make `point *readPoint(point *p)`, then check the return of `scanf` and `if (scanf("%lf%lf", &p->x, &p->y) < 2) return NULL; return p;` and continue that logic back up the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine your `readPoint()` and `readRectangle()` functions more like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { double x, y; } point;
typedef struct { point a, b, c, d; } rectangle;   

bool readPoint(point *p)
{
    if (scanf("%lf%lf", &p->x, &p->y) != 2)
        return false;
    return true;
}

bool readRectangle(rectangle *r)
{
    if (!readPoint(&r->c) || !readPoint(&r->b))
        return false;
    r->a.x = r->c.x;
    r->a.y = r->b.y;
    r->d.x = r->b.x;
    r->d.y = r->c.y;
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
        rectangle r;
        printf("Enter rectangle: ");
        if (!readRectangle(&r))
            break;   
        …
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is one of the strategies you outlined — it is probably the best.  You could continue to return the structures and pass a status variable in via a pointer (`point readPoint(int *status)`) — it would work, though it isn't the conventional way to do it.

A more outré technique would use `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` from `<setjmp.h>`; you'd call `setjmp()` in the `main()` function, and call `longjmp()` when your input code detected a problem.  I'd not recommend this — just outlining an alternative.

Yes, you could abbreviate `readPoint()` to:

```
bool readPoint(point *p)
{
    return scanf("%lf%lf", &p->x, &p->y) == 2;
}
```

Comment: Much less modification than handling pointers back up from `readPoint`.

Comment: r.a.x=r.c.x;
    r.a.y=r.b.y;
    r.d.x=r.b.x;
    r.d.y=r.c.y;

the compiler doesnt realize these are part of a structure.... do they have to be pointers too?... pointers confuse me still

Comment: I had to fix my version of your code to use `r->a.x`, etc. because `r` is now a `rectangle *` instead of a `rectangle` structure.  I did that a while ago, though.

Answer (score 1):

So as bad of an idea this is, I'm going to provide the literal answer to this question. Yes, you can do this. You had better have a darn good reason to do this because or others will scream in horror at the code you have created.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

typedef struct{double x,y;} point;
typedef struct{point a,b,c,d;} rectangle;
typedef struct{point o; double r;} circle;

point readPoint(jmp_buf jmp){
    point p;
    if (scanf("%lf%lf", &p.x, &p.y) != 2)     /*type "quit"*/
        longjmp(jmp, 1); /* returns to setjmp() call with 1 */
    return p;
}

rectangle readRectangle(jmp_buf jmp){
    rectangle r;
    r.c=readPoint(jmp);
    r.b=readPoint(jmp);
    r.a.x=r.c.x;
    r.a.y=r.b.y;
    r.d.x=r.b.x;
    r.d.y=r.c.y;
    return r;
}

int main(void) {
    jmp_buf jmp;
    if (setjmp(jmp) == 0) {
        while(1){
            int a=0;
            rectangle r;
            circle c;
            printf("Enter rectangle:");
            r=readRectangle(jmp);
            printf("Enter circle:");
            c=readCircle(jmp);
            a=overlap(r, c);
            if (a==1)
                printf("The rectangle and the circle overlap.\n\n");
            else
                printf("The rectangle and the circle do not overlap.\n\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Program completed normally.");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Learning by *counter-example*, priceless!

Answer (score 0):

I would have your readPoint method return 0/1 to indicate a success or fail reading then pass your result back by reference.

This keeps your data clean, as opposed to passing an isBadData flag with every result.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a little modification in readPoint().

```
point readPoint(){
int s;
point p;
s=scanf("%lf%lf", &p.x, &p.y);
if(s==0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
return p;
}
```

If the values are not entered or if they are not as per the format then `s=0` as it is the value returned by `scanf()`. For more information visit http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Include stdlib.h header file to use exit function.

Comment: Unilaterally exiting from in a library function is seldom a good idea.

Comment: yepp it's not a good idea, anyways it works in case of this program.